# GetDirectories returns me a string c#

Tags: c#, directory, subdirectory, getdirectories

Hello Im currently during get Directories as the following:

```
dirs = Directory
  .GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\jphillips\Desktop\test", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
  .Where(Path => reg.IsMatch(Path))
  .ToList();
```

With this I can filter through all the subdirectories in a directory and filter the ones I want with the regex I provided below:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\d+(\.\d+)+");
```

My problem is with my new list of strings of directory paths. I want to use directoryinfo functions on them such as Parent and get directories of those directories to so stuff. IS there a way to convert my string paths to directyinfo types. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `DirectoryInfo` for the root path, and work with that instead of paths:

```
var rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\jphillips\Desktop\test");
dirs = rootDir.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
              .Where(d => reg.IsMatch(d.FullName))
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the DirectoryInfo class to do this, and feed the DirectoryInfo.Name property to your regex instead of the whole DirectoryInfo instance.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp");
DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = di.GetDirectories().Where(d => reg.IsMatch(d.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since Directory.GetDicrectories returns an array of strings, what you can do is add a select to your LINQ statement

```
 dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\jphillips\Desktop\test", "*",
        SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Path => reg.IsMatch(Path)).Select(x => new
        DirectoryInfo(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: There is no reason to do that since DirectoryInfo already has this functionality built it.